# Moser method to prove Holder regualrity

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $Lu=D_i(a^{i,j}(x)D_j u+b^{i}u)+c^{i}D_i u+d(x)u,$ where is uniformly elliptic, that is,  $a^{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j\geq\lambda |\xi|^{2}$ for all $\xi\in\mathbf{R}^{n}$ and $x\in \Omega.$ Also
$ \lambda^{-2}\sum \big(|b^{i}(x)|^{2}+|c^{i}(x)|^{2}\big)+\lambda^{-1}|d(x)|\leq \nu^{2}$ for some positive $\lambda,\nu.$

**Theorem 8.18**[of the book David Gilberg and N.S Trudinger, Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order]
Suppose that $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is a supersolution of $Lu=D_i f^{i}+g$ with $f^{i}\in L^{q}$, $g\in L^{q/2}$ for some $q>n.$ Suppose $u$ is nonnegative in the ball $B_{4R}(y)\subset\Omega$ and $1\leq p<n/(n-2),$ we have

$R^{-(n/p)}$ $\|u\|_{L^{p}(B_{2R}(y))}$ $\leq C\big( \inf_{B_R(y)}u+K(R)\big)$

**In the proof** the authors have used $v=\eta^{2}\overline{u}^{\beta},$ where $\overline{u}=u+k$ with $k>0$ and $\eta$ is a standard cutoff function, as a test function in the weak formulation of elliptic equations. My question is that how to show that for any $\beta\in \mathbf{R}$ and $u\in W^{1,2}(B_4)$ the function $v\in W^{1,2}_{0}(B_4)?$